# php css setting css definnitions in a class

Tags: php

I am very new to php, had some 16 years in .net c#, but
I came across this class (I'm doing an event driven calendar) and would like to know how to use it.

```
 /**
 * holds all of the css class definitions
 *
 * @var array
 * @access private
 */
 private $_class_defintions = array();

 // [...]

 public function setCssDefinitions(array $settings = array()){
        $this->_class_defintions = array_merge($this->_class_defintions, $settings);

        return $this;
 }

// [...]
```

In the calendar build function there are statements like this:

```
$rows[] = $this->row($cells, $this->_class_defintions['row']);
and 
$this->_class_defintions['calendar'] 
$this->_class_defintions['month_head']
```

I assume I need a css.php file, with items like 'row' and 'calendar' and 'month_head' etc., include it and then somehow put that through to the 
 `function setCssDefinitions(array $settings = array())` as an associative array. But that's where I'm stuck.

*How to read it in as an associative array* (with the array items 'row', 'calendar', maybe 'cell', 'header' etc) which then gets sent as a param to the `setCssDefinitions()` function.

Thanks.

Comment: That is very little to go on.